How do I Remove this old drain?
I am replacing the shower pan because it's cracked. I googled and it seems there are drains with a metal thing you twist and drains with a black rubber thing you drill holes it to loosen it, then pull it out with needle nose pliers.
I tried drilling, but it appears the stuff that looks like putty (because it's so uneven) is metal. The shards from drilling were silver and grey (my dad liked to over-secure things - could be some kind of liquid nails).
There doesn't appear to be any way to unscrew it (if it's a screw-off flange) without removing what looks like the grey / metal goop.
I also saw a googled post saying to cut through the pipe with a Dremmel.  I'm afraid the pipe will then be too short, so I'll wait for more advice, if that's the way to go.
I thought about cutting around the drain and removing the shower pan so I can look from underneath. The shower pan I believe is set in cement (crumbled cement, hence the crack), so I'm not sure what I'll get once that's attempted.
Here is a picture of the drain. Thank you in advance! (I sprayed WD-40, that's the liquid in the picture. And the rag is there, I took it out for the picture so you could see all the edges.)


before anything, fill the drain hole with paper towels to prevent anything falling in it

Thank you!  I have a washcloth there, but I took it out for the picture.  I guess If I have to cut the pipe with a drummel paper towel will be better.

you need Reverse-Action Clamping Plier,

you cut the pipe that it is welded to and undo the nut on the underside.
seeing as the pan is coming out anyway start by sawing the pan up so you can see how the pipes are connected.
